# One server 2 NIC's 2 different networks

Tags: windows-server-2003, networking, virtualization, virtual-machines

I have a windows server 2003 box with 2 NIC's and I added a virtual machine running inside of windows on that box. I need that VM on a different network, so I dedicated the 2nd NIC to that VM and it works fine. But.... I can no longer access the server through the assigned IP, but can access it through the IP that gets assigned to the 2nd NIC (thats for the VM).

The 2nd NIC for the VM is hooked to a gigabit switch, and the main sever NIC is hooked to a 100mbit switch and thus changes the metric in the route table to be lower for the VM NIC cause it being on gigabit. I dont have access to the server right now to show the route print out, but I can on monday when I get back  to work.

I need to be able to access the main windows sever on the assigned IP on the 1st NIC, I have too many things setup that point at that IP.

I'm not sure if this makes any diff but... The gigabit switch that the 2nd VM NIC is hooked to is on a prvate VLAN. The private VLAN and the normal LAN are able to talk to each other just fine(they each have their own gateway that is routed back and forth between each other on the layer 3 switch), it is setup this way to prevent dhcp broadcasts from reaching the other side of the network so computers on each side dont get the wrong IP.

*EDIT* here is the ipconfig and the route print

```
Windows IP Configuration

Ethernet adapter APS:
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.61.11.43
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.248.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.61.8.2

Ethernet adapter FOG:
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.61.64.150
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.61.64.1

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Interface List
0x1 ........................... MS TCP Loopback interface
0x2 ...00 24 81 e8 7e e4 ...... HP NC382i DP Multifunction Gigabit Server Adapter #3 - VirtualBox Bridged Networking Driver Miniport
0x50004 ...00 24 81 e8 7e ea ...... HP NC382i DP Multifunction Gigabit Server Adapter #2 - VirtualBox Bridged Networking Driver Miniport
===========================================================================
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0        10.61.8.2      10.61.11.43     20
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0       10.61.64.1     10.61.64.150     10
        10.61.8.0    255.255.248.0      10.61.11.43      10.61.11.43     20
      10.61.11.43  255.255.255.255        127.0.0.1        127.0.0.1     20
       10.61.64.0    255.255.255.0     10.61.64.150     10.61.64.150     10
     10.61.64.150  255.255.255.255        127.0.0.1        127.0.0.1     10
   10.255.255.255  255.255.255.255      10.61.11.43      10.61.11.43     20
   10.255.255.255  255.255.255.255     10.61.64.150     10.61.64.150     10
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0        127.0.0.1        127.0.0.1      1
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0      10.61.11.43      10.61.11.43     20
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0     10.61.64.150     10.61.64.150     10
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255      10.61.11.43      10.61.11.43      1
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255     10.61.64.150     10.61.64.150      1
Default Gateway:        10.61.64.1
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

Everytime that I enable the NIC with the 10.61.64.150 IP I lose all connectivity except ping to the 10.61.11.43 IP

Comment: it would help to know what virtualization software you are using.

Comment: What is the output of `ipconfig`? Can you ping anyone from on the server? Can you ping the server from the network? Is there a firewall enabled?

Comment: I am using Virtual box.

Comment: The ipconfig shows both network adapters enables with IP's from their respective networks.

Comment: And I can ping both NIC's and including the VM from the network.

Answer (score 0):

On the VM host, unbind TCP/IP from the gigabit card. Then configure the networking in virtualbox to 'bridged' on that gig card.